# ${\{f_n(y)\}}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges $\implies S=\{0\} $True/false

Tags: real-analysis

Is  the following statement  true/false?

Let  ${\{f_n\}}_{n=1}^{\infty}$  be  the  sequence  of  functions on  $\mathbb R$  defined  by  $$f_n(x)=n^2x^n.$$ Let $S$  be  the  set of all  points  $y$  in  $\mathbb R$  such  that the  sequence  ${\{f_n(y)\}}_{n=1}^{\infty}$  converges . Then ,$S=\{0\}.$

**My attempt** : I thinkthis statement is true.

Here $S=\{0\} \implies  S=[0,0]$

Now take  $y \in [0,0]$ then  $$\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(y)=n^2y^n=\lim_{n \to \infty} n^2.0=\infty.0=0$$

Comment: Look at $x=1/2$.

Comment: @DavidMitra but $1/2 \notin [0,0]$

Comment: But is $S$ as advertised?

Comment: No @DavidMitra  my  thinking is that  $f_n:\{0\} \to \mathbb{R} $ defined by $f_n(x)=n^2x^n$

Comment: The question [Difficulty with limit to show pointwise convergence (without L'hospital's rule)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2786658/difficulty-with-limit-to-show-pointwise-convergence-without-lhospitals-rule) has a TL;DR which is proved by various answers to it : the up shot of all these answers is that $(0,1) \subset S$ i.e. that $S$ definitely contains more elements than just $\{0\}$. So that answers your question,if you have doubts regarding any of those approaches, kindly comment beneath those posts asking for clarification (I have checked and you have the reputation to do so).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, namely the set of all $y\in\mathbb{R}$ for which $f_n(y)$ converges. Let's split this into three cases:

- If $x=\pm 1$, $f_n(1)=n^2, f_n(-1)=(-1)n^2$ both don't converge.
- If $x>1$, then $f_n(x)=x^nn^2\to\infty $ simply because both $x^n$ and $n^2$ converge to $\infty$. Same for $x<-1$.
- If $0<x<1$, then: $f_n(x)=x^nn^2$. But here, $x^n\to 0$ much faster than $n^2\to\infty$, and therefore $f_n(x)\to 0$. Same goes (up to sign) for $-1<x\leq0$.

Therefore, $S=(-1,1)$, as opposed to what you wrote.

Notice that the statement can be shown to be false without doing all I did but by simply looking at for example $x=\frac{1}{4}$, but I wanted to show you the idea.